# how can I run my python code using my GPU in spyder (anaconda3)?

Tags: gpu, spyder, anaconda3

I'm trying to use my GPU (Nvidia GeForce) to run my python code in spyder, and I don't know the way to do it.

any help please !

Answer (score 1):

Most cases you need these things:

Be sure that your GPU is compatible from:
https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus

Download Cuda ToolKit:
https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads

You can check by `nvidia-smi` command if it works

Install `conda install cudatoolkit`

You may also need `conda install numba` depending on your code

Also checkout: https://www.anaconda.com/blog/getting-started-with-gpu-computing-in-anaconda

And if you don't use anaconda you can download packages via pip checkout: https://documen.tician.de/pycuda/

Comment: thank you for the steps, I do all of that, now the issue is how I can explore those tools to run my python code ?

Comment: Is it for machine learning task with tensorflow or pytorch or not ?
If not you can check this blog post: https://towardsdatascience.com/python-performance-and-gpus-1be860ffd58d

Comment: Not for tensorflow or pythorch, I'm using it for a features selection (Brute force), I have more data and if I use the CPU its take long time, I tried to use @numba.cuda.jit but isn't work

Comment: This is an extremely misleading answer. There is no way to run arbitrary Python code on a CUDA GPU. Numba allows code which uses a tiny subset of the Python language to be compiled for the GPU. Other frameworks use GPU acceleration for parts of  their workflow. PyCUDA GPU code is all written in C++. Nothing here answers the question -- the only answer is "you almost certainly can't do what you ask"

Comment: @talonmies just by looking at your profile I can understand you are more experienced on the subject than me clearly. However this is a very generalised question without any code whatsoever. Therefore I wanted to give an idea about cuda driver and getting started documentation. This question cannot have a clear defined answer by the nature of it. Therefore if you have any suggestions about writing Python code such that can run on GPU, it would be very appreciative both for me and the owner of the question.

Comment: That is precisely why you shouldn't answer questions like this at all. It is far to general and there isn't a constructive answer to provide. Case in point: the OP of this question went on to ask another related question which was closed and downvoted into oblivion specifically because of the poor advice received here. Which is why I felt obligated to comment.

Comment: @talonmies  I see your point, thank you for the feedback :)